# How to place background images on HTML emails with dynamic height from table row?

Tags: office365, html-email, microsoft365

I am creating HTML emails and would like a background image in the table row section to show the background images behind the table cells in that row.

As I understand, for Microsoft Outlook, I need to use table structure, and read articles like these:

https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/html-background-images-in-email/
http://www.emaildesignreview.com/email-code/html-bulletproof-background-images-in-email-3850/
https://backgrounds.cm/
https://buttons.cm/

Those pages specify a width and height, but I want a dynamic width and height that fills the table row behind the contents of the table row.

I have tried VML already and it places the background over the top of the background and messes up the table width.

So far I get this far with a layout like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
<!--[if mso]><xml><o:OfficeDocumentSettings><o:AllowPNG/><o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch></o:OfficeDocumentSettings></xml><![endif]-->
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport"/>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
</head>
<body id="body">
<div style="display: block; width: 100%;">      
<table role="presentation" align="center" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed;mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; table-layout:fixed; width: 600px;">
<tr cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="img.jpg" style="background-image: url(img.jpg); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;">

<!--[if mso]>
<v:rect fill="true" stroke="false" style="width: 600px;">
<v:fill type="frame" src="img.jpg"/>';
<v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
</v:rect>
<![endif]-->

<td colspan="3">
<p style="text-align: center;">Heading</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%" height="100px"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetuer</a> adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, <a href="#">justo</a>. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a,</p></td>
<td width="50%" height="100px"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a,</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have experimented with the inline styles with mso-width-percent, mso-height-percent, width, height. Still does not fit the specified 600px. I would like the background to be like this CSS:

```css
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
```

The v:textbox however, is no good as the content would have links provided in the table cell.

With CSS capable clients it works as expected and is far easier but does not work with Outlook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I recently wrote about [background properties in VML](https://www.hteumeuleu.com/2021/background-properties-in-vml/). Here are the equivalents in VML for the `<v:fill>` element of the CSS properties you mentioned:

- `type="frame"` is equivalent to `background-repeat: no-repeat;`
- `origin="0,0" position="0,0"` is equivalent to `background-position: center;` (it is also the default values for `<v:fill>` so we can simply omit this)
- `aspect="atleast"` is equivalent to `background-size: cover;`

Also a few notes on the code you posted:

- The end of your `<v:fill>` element has an extra quote and semicolon (`<v:fill type="frame" src="img.jpg"/>';`)
- In VML, the `</v:textbox>` and `</v:rect>` must be closed after the content you want over your background.
- Applying the CSS background to a `<tr>` feels a bit sketchy to me. Although this might just be a personal preference, I would rather use a `<div>` here.
- The HTML `background` is really not necessary nowadays. The [CSS background property](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-background/) is pretty well supported now.

Here’s a full example of code I rewrote:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Background</title>
    <!--[if mso]>
    <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:600px; margin:0 auto;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="background:0 0/cover; background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/d4mw7CC.jpg); background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <!--[if mso]>
                                <v:rect filled="true" stroked="false" style="width:600px;">
                                    <v:fill aspect="atleast" type="frame" src="https://i.imgur.com/d4mw7CC.jpg" />
                                    <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                                <![endif]-->
                                <p style="text-align: center;">Heading</p>
                                <!--[if mso]>
                                    </v:textbox>
                                </v:rect>
                                <![endif]-->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%" height="100px"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetuer</a> adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, <a href="#">justo</a>. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a,</p></td>
                        <td width="50%" height="100px"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a,</p></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And here you can see [tests screenshots on Email on Acid](https://app.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/7nfDBtbQvZoDuOJSDrAf3COQzC3YEgROa6CI20MSQzpkF/list).

Comment: I have followed your advice and got the image now in place, however the text is missing, which I used HTML, that I inserted elements like div and table, nothing is showing as text above the image in Outlook. But works fine in the browser. An alteration I have done to my email is that I specified a height for the table row this time to also put with the VML in the rectangle box.

Comment: Oops, my bad! I actually missed a closing slash on the `<v:fill>` element. Adding it fixes the issue. I edited the code above. Here are rendering for the Outlooks on Windows: https://app.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/HIFpowa4cbqFWS911niB0deTHfBKFOh67TfWQD9yPJsYV/list